# org-mode macros inside code blocks and using babel

Tags: emacs, elasticsearch, org-mode

Inspired by this [great post](http://writequit.org/articles/literate-es-scripts.html), I'm trying to use the combination of `org-mode` and `babel` for issuing queries to `elasticsearch`. For example, counting the number of entries in an index:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
curl -XGET 'http://my.uri.example:8080/index/_count'
#+END_SRC
```

The above code can be evaluated using `C-c C-c` when the point is in the block.<sup>1</sup>

On the other hand, one can define [macros](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html) in the org document. My question is: is it possible to define a macro

```
#+MACRO: live-db http://my.uri.example:8080
```

and rewrite the code block as follow:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
curl -XGET '{{{live-db}}}/index/_count'
#+END_SRC
```

Out of the box, for me, it didn't work... It seems like `babel` is not expanding the macro before the evaluation of the block. Ideas?

## Edit

Now, once I learned that I can use [`es-mode`](https://github.com/dakrone/es-mode), I won't to fine tune my question. Consider the following two requests:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC es :url http://mu.uri.stage:8080
GET /users/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  }
}
#+END_SRC
```

and

```
#+BEGIN_SRC es :url http://mu.uri.live:8080
GET /users/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  }
}
#+END_SRC
```

They merely differ in the URL. I would like to define two macros:

```
#+MACRO staging http://my.uri.stage:8080
#+MACRO live http://my.uri.live:8080
```

and then use the macros as the variables of the blocks. Is it possible?

---

<sup>1</sup> Make sure you enable the evaluation of `sh`. Add something like:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((sh . t)))
```

to your `.emacs`.

Comment: Regarding your first question, see lines 3088-3089 of ox.el:

Comment: Macros ARE expanded before Babel code is evaluated.

Comment: (function org-export-as)

Comment: Maybe this should be asked to the Org ML; Nicolas would surely answer you.

Comment: @fniessen, I think he's trying to execute, not export.. Anyway, even though macros are expanded before babel code is executed, they are not expanded inside source blocks (see [lines 180-192 in lisp/org-macro.el](http://repo.or.cz/w/org-mode.git?a=blame_incremental;hb=fa64b59b05a2344de2d377bf30004d50a73dd4cf;f=lisp%2Forg-macro.el#l176))

Comment: See [that answer on Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48741/2370) for an Elisp snippet that adds expansion of org-macros in source block header arguments.

Answer (score 5):

macro expansion is not natively supported when executing code blocks, but the [Noweb reference syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-reference-syntax.html) which is supported is much more powerful.

However, I doubt that it will work using `es-mode`, since it passes the url in a [header argument](http://orgmode.org/manual/Specific-header-arguments.html) and not a [variable](http://orgmode.org/manual/var.html).

This is a simple example for a `sh` code block:

```
#+name: staging
: http://my.uri.stage:8080

#+name: live
: http://my.uri.live:8080

#+name: test
#+begin_src sh :var url=staging
echo $url
#+end_src

#+call: test(live)

#+RESULTS:
: http://my.uri.live:8080

#+call: test(staging)

#+RESULTS:
: http://my.uri.stage:8080
```